# install sparks, why there is a option for package type

Tags: apache-spark

I try to download sparks, and I see there is an option, that lets you to choose the package's type. Something like pre-built for hadoop version number. What does it mean? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this answer quite informative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210247/what-does-pre-built-for-apache-hadoop-2-7-and-later-mean

Answer (score 0):

They correspond to different frameworks builds, for example the `pre-build` means that everything is already compiled and packed for others usage, therefore you don't have worry about reading the documentation about how to compile `Spark`, some users have old versions of `Hadoop` and can't update them to newer versions for any reason (maybe they work in different departments and the system administrators are afraid of breaking something, other possibility is that they are using old/deprecated functionalities that aren't supported by newer versions, or they just don't want to update), so you have the possibility of selecting one of the other downloads.

On the other hand, you can download the source and compile it depending on your needs, besides some contributors prefer to have the source to test their changes before making a formal pull request to the project.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but I dont understand why "some users have old versions of Hadoop and can't update them to newer versions" related to install sparks, can you please explain it more?

Comment: @user3033715 Most of my explanation are based in my and other's experience