# What does "pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7 and later" mean?

Tags: apache-spark

What does "pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7 and later" mean on the download page of Apache Spark?

Does it mean necessary libraries for HDFS in spark? If so, how about other storage systems like Cassandra, s3, HBase, SQL Databases, NoSQL databases?  Do we need to download any libraries to connect to other storage systems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it mean necessary libraries for HDFS in spark

Correct! Spark uses Hadoop FileSystem API to access files (on HDFS and S3 and other HDFS-supported file systems) and "pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7 and later" version comes with the necessary libraries included.

That's mainly for Spark Core's RDD to access files with data.

> how about other storage systems like Cassandra, s3, HBase, SQL Databases, NoSQL databases?
> Do we need to download any libraries to connect to other storage systems.

Out of the mentioned storage systems, S3 is covered partially by the "pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7 and later" bundle (but you have to add additional jars for S3 specifically).

That's mostly for Spark SQL's Dataset API.

Cassandra, HBase, etc. have their own Spark connectors and are not included. See [DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) and [Apache HBase Connector](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc)

---

If you've been wondering "If I have to run spark on YARN which package type to use" just use "Pre-built for Apache Hadoop" with the version of Hadoop ("2.7" vs "3.2 and later") as the version of Hadoop in use (which is likely the version of Hadoop YARN).

---

So "spark-prebuilt-with-hadoop-x.y" means that Spark includes Hadoop x.y in jars directory. That obviously makes the distribution larger than "spark-without-hadoop". It also means that once you upgrade your HDFS to Hadoop 3.2 but the Spark distribution was "with Hadoop 2.7" you can still use it but some features won't simply be supported and your application can be less optimized (by HDFS itself) not to mention all the bugs fixed (and new introduced).

---

> Wouldn't there be a conflict between hadoop jars present in spark-prebuilt-with-hadoop-x.y and those that in hadoop-x.y? spark-prebuilt-with-hadoop-x.y gave me the impression that all necessary hadoop stuff (e.g., YARN) would be present in the spark binary. Hence my confusion that all hadoop should be present in the umbrella spark-prebuilt-with-hadoop-x.y.

Not really if you think about the underlying communication between Spark app and Hadoop DFS or Hadoop YARN. It's between separate applications living in their own containers (possibly in Docker) so their CLASSPATHs are separated.

The only issue could be mismatches in protocols of Hadoop components and Spark and that's why you should be as compatible with the jars as possible and use the Spark bundle that is the closest to your Hadoop env version-wise.

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you very much for your time and patience. My doubts have finally been cleared!